# Ext JS 4 - how to change content of an item which can't be referenced by an ID

Tags: extjs4

I would really appreciate any help with the following problem:

I need to be able to change content of an item (div or textfield) but the problem is that there are going to be multiple instances of the same window so I cannot use div IDs.

I tried this little example:

```
var myBtnHandler = function(btn) {
    myPanel.items.items[0].html = "Changed by click!";
    myPanel.doLayout();
}

var fileBtn = new Ext.Button({
    text : 'Change',
    handler : myBtnHandler
});

var panel1 = {
    html : 'Original content.'
};

var myPanel = new Ext.Window({
    title : 'How to change it?',
    items : [
        panel1,
        fileBtn
    ]
});
myPanel.items.items[0].html = "Changed on load!";
myPanel.show();
```

Referencing an element by myPanel.items.items[0] works on load but does not work when it's in the button handler - is it a scope-related problem? How to reference an element without its ID?

Thank you very much,

H.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with scope. The first time you set the html property, the component has not yet been rendered, so on initial render it will read the html property off the component. The second time, you're just setting a property on an object, it's not going to react in any way.

Instead, you should use the update() method.

```
Ext.require('*');

Ext.onReady(function() {
    var myBtnHandler = function(btn) {
        myPanel.items.first().update("Changed by click!");
    }
    var fileBtn = new Ext.Button({
        text: 'Change',
        handler: myBtnHandler
    });

    var panel1 = {
        html: 'Original content.'
    };

    var myPanel = new Ext.Window({
        title: 'How to change it?',
        items: [panel1, fileBtn]
    });
    myPanel.items.items[0].html = "Changed on load!";
    myPanel.show();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't make it work - no matter how I re-order the code, no matter whether I use doLayout() or update(). Could you please provide some working code?

Answer (score 1):

There are several functions that go through elements that belongs to a container. Try using for example down():

```
btn = panel.down('button');
```

Where 'button' parameter would mean 'give me element which type is equal to 'button'. Check out Sencha doc for querying various elements too: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Sha's reply. To put his advice in context with your example.

```
var myBtnHandler = function(btn) {
    btn.up('window').down('panel').update('Changed by click!');
}

var fileBtn = new Ext.Button({
    text : 'Change',
    handler : myBtnHandler
});

var panel1 = {
    html : 'Original content.'
};

var myPanel = new Ext.Window({
    title : 'How to change it?',
    items : [
        panel1,
        fileBtn
    ]
});

myPanel.show();
myPanel.update('Changed on load!');
```

Comment: This solution also works - thank you guys, all of you have been very helpful.

Comment: No problem, but I would strongly advise against using items.items[0] to reference your components. Getting into that habit will lead to bugs if you add in components and forget to update index values.